# Multiple JSONArray to Array or List

Tags: arrays, json, sqlite, multidimensional-array

I have saved my JSONs in a database and I want to get specific objects from every entry.
I'll show it:

```
[
   {
      "Messungen":[
         {
            "car":"no Car choosed",
            "g":0.2,
            "time":"[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]",
            "max":66,
            "secondText":"0 - 200 km\/h",
            "speed":"[63, 61, 63, 62, 63, 64, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 64, 63, 63]",
            "tosecond":"\/",
            "to100":"\/",
            "way":209,
            "avg":63
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Messungen":[
         {
            "car":"no Car choosed",
            "g":0.2,
            "time":"[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]",
            "max":70,
            "secondText":"0 - 200 km\/h",
            "speed":"[59, 61, 61, 61, 62, 60, 61, 62, 61, 62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 63, 63, 64, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 67, 69, 69, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 69, 70, 70, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 68, 66, 66]",
            "tosecond":"\/",
            "to100":"\/",
            "way":808,
            "avg":65
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to get the way and the car from the Array Messungen as a List or Array. 
Is that possible or should I make two new entries in the database with these two types?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you saving whole JSON structures as-is in your database, or is that the output of some script which reads the database and converts it to JSON? The first option would be quite useless IMHO. Also, you're supposed to show what you have tried and point out the actually issues you encountered.

Comment: Ok sorry.. I didn't want to create so many rows in the database so I've put them in a JSON String. As a result every entry has an ID, a JSON String and a timestamp. Now I want to create a ListView with the row car and way. But I don't know how to get only the way and the car from so many JSON Strings.. Do you understand ?

Comment: In what language do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

Databases are designed to be good at managing many, many rows. Use the power of the database. Create a table called "Messung" and make each observation (car, g, way, u.s.w) a column in the table.

Comment: Actually, time and speed would probably be better as separate tables joined with the first one.

Comment: You're right.. I think I'll seperate the two columns ;)